# What is the better way to store global objects rather than Singleton classes

Tags: android, kotlin

I am building an android application which contains some activities that fetch datat using retrofit client. For now, i have resorted to creating instances in each activity that requires it. However, ofc this is probably not the best solution out there. Then i came across Singletons, however, then there is a hell of it being pretty bad solution.

Making singletons did work, but according to internet, it is not the best solution due to many issues. So, what is the best way to do it now?

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by singletons?  There are good and bad ways of doing it.

Comment: Singletons classes, for which yoyu only need to initialize once and then you get can the data back without creating any more instance (reusing)

Comment: That sounds like the usual and preferable solution.

Comment: Oh... okay thjen, thenks!